# HttpClient with a potential redirect?

Tags: c#, httpclient

There seems to a redirect in this URL?

Code:

```
                using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
                {            
                    var jsonRersponse = http.GetStringAsync("https://www.buchhandel.de/jsonapi/products?filter[products][query]=(st=Romane,%20Lyrik)%20und%20ej=2000^*&filter[keepPage]=true&page[number]=18&page[size]=100&sort[score]=desc").Result;
                    Bla myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bla>(jsonRersponse);                         
                }
```

I get:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 404 ().)'

Opening the URL in the browser results in (,but finally getting the result):

[image: Opening]

What can I do?

Comment: I don't see what one has to do with the other. One is a warning generated by the browser itself.

Comment: I suggest you use a tool like Telerik's Fiddler to analyse the request .NET is making and compare it to that of your browser. I notice that .NET is encoding the caret (`^`) in your query as `%5E`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the Accept header.
I found you need to set the Accept header to make that url respond with data.
I discovered this playing around in Powershell

```
$url='/jsonapi/products?filter[products][query]=(st=Romane,%20Lyrik)%20und%20ej=2000^*&filter[keepPage]=true&page[number]=18&page[size]=100&sort[score]=desc'
$host1='https://www.buchhandel.de'
$uri = new-object System.Uri ($host1 + $url2),$true
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient

#Accept header is required
$client.Headers.Add("Accept","*/*")

$s = $client.DownloadString($uri)
$client.Dispose()
Write-Host $s
```

In C#:

```
using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
{    
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");      
    var jsonRersponse = http.GetStringAsync("https://www.buchhandel.de/jsonapi/products?filter[products][query]=(st=Romane,%20Lyrik)%20und%20ej=2000^*&filter[keepPage]=true&page[number]=18&page[size]=100&sort[score]=desc").Result;
    Bla myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bla>(jsonRersponse);                         
}
```